# How to solve a dual Lp graphically?

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider the following LP:
>
> $$\min 24x_1-9x_2+8x_4 $$
>
> such that
> \begin{align}
>     4x_1-9x_2+3x_3+4x_4 &= 2 \\
>     3x_1-x_2-10x_3-x_4 &= 1 \\
>     x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 &\ge 0
> \end{align}

Draw the the corresponding column vectors $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, b$ as well as the dual feasible solution set graphically.
Obtain a dual optimal solution from the sketch and use it to compute a primal optimal solution.

I have drawn the column vectors with [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/vm25z9r4). But I do not understand how I should now draw the dual feasible solution set and so on.
Could you explain that to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the dual you turn the Min to a Max, flip the directions of the inequalities (a Min’s standard form has $\geq$’s), turn variables into constraints and turn constraints into variables. This is with an inequality leading to a non-negative variable and an equality leading to a free variable. This is why the column vectors are important; they are describing the constraints of the dual problem. With this in mind, the dual has the following form:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Max } 2y_1+y_2,\text{st:}&\\
4y_1+3y_2\leq 24,&\\
-9y_1-1y_2\leq -9,&\\
3y_1-10y_2\leq 0,&\\
4y_1-1y_2\leq 8,&\\
y_1,y_2\ \text{free}.
\end{align}$$
Since this linear programming problem only has two variables, this dual problem can have its feasible region can be plotted according to the above.

I hope this helps!
Many thanks